# Convert JS date to Apex format

Tags: javascript, date

I am calculating date in JS in the below format:

```
var startnew= new Date(currentYear,3*currQuarter-2,1);
var enddatenew= new Date(currentYear,3*currQuarter+1,0);
```

In Apex :

```
List<String> parts = startnew.split('T');

List<String> partstart = parts[0].split('-');

String startdate = partstart[1]+'/'+partstart[2]+'/'+partstart[0];

date startdateformat= date.parse(startdate);
List<String> parts2 = enddatenew.split('T');
List<String> partend = parts2[0].split('-');
String enddate = partend[1]+'/'+partend[2]+'/'+partend[0];
date enddateformat= date.parse(enddate);


  I want to do a SOQL  like :
select Fields__c from CustomObject__c  where   createdDate>=: startdateformat AND createdDate>=: enddateformat
```

What corrections needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`Date.Parse()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse) method

> parse(stringDate)
>
> Constructs a Date from a String. The format of the String depends on
>   the local date format.

```
date mydate = date.parse('12/27/2009');
```

In your case

```
Date dtStart = date.parse(startnew);
Date dtEnd = date.parse(enddatenew);

select Fields__c from CustomObject__c 
 where createdDate>=: dtStart AND createdDate>=: dtEnd
```

### Updates

You can also use Period object here to get the quarter start and end date.

```
List<Period> Dates = [Select type, StartDate, EndDate 
                       From Period WHERE type = 'Quarter' 
                        AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER];
Date StartDateQuarter = Dates[0].StartDate;
Date EndDateQuarter = Dates[0].EndDate;
```

try like this now use

```
StartDateQuarter and EndDateQuarter in query
AND ( createdDate>=: quarterstartdate AND createdDate>=: quarterenddate )
```

Comment: @Ratan-  To test the method from dev console , it will not allow me to call with the JS format date , right? e.g methodname(id , Thu May 12 2016 19:25:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),Thu May 21 2016 19:25:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))

Comment: @SFDCRookie you need to use this date as string `methodname(id , 'Thu May 12 2016 19:25:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 'Thu May 21 2016 19:25:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')`

Comment: A related question to test this . My method signature is methodname((List<String> Ids, String startdate,String enddate ) - I am passing a single id as the first parameter . Is that not correct?

Comment: @SFDCRookie if you are passing single Id then Your method should looks like `methodname((Id newId, String startdate,String enddate )`

Comment: My question is what value should I put to test my method where the parameter is a string type List ? Can you give an example of the whole syntax please?

Comment: @SFDCRookie I am just curious what you used in javascript you are getting date in this format `Thu May 12 2016 19:25:44 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` ?

Comment: I have used the one I put in the question . In alert also it's showing the same format. Is there  something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39716/discussion-between-ratan-and-sfdcrookie).